# What's the best way to find the CMYK and RGB of a HTML color?

Tags: color, print-design

I found some colors on the web that I'd like to use in my print brochure. What's the best way to find the CMYK equivalent of a HTML color?

Comment: I like to use the ColorPicker Plugin for Chrome to get colors of a website. You can also inspect the html and get the hex color that way. If you want a RGB value from a Hex you can use http://hex.colorrrs.com/. There are also other generators for rgb or hex to cmyk

Comment: Color conversion is not that straightforward. There is a *physical* difference between RGB (light) and CMYK (ink), which makes it impossible to convert some colors.

Comment: What's the purpose? Do you just want "something close" or are you concerned about an *exact* color? HTML (or Hex) **is** RGB.

Comment: I'm starting a branding guide for my company so I want to provide the color in CMYK, RGB and HEX

Comment: 'starting a branding guide for my company' - your best option if you are in at the start is to choose brand colours that are close across RGB, CMYK and Pantone (for spot printing) rather than randomly choosing colours. I have a Pantone swatch set for this and its been reliable over the years. I generally start with CMYK so that I can control the print consistency and cost without difficult Pantone's like Reflex Blue. Starting at the website is troublesome - its RGB for screen and a wider gamut than print (simple terms - some RGB colours don't convert - bright orange an example).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to talk to your printer and borrow their CMYK or spot colour Pantone® book. There’s just no quick or reliable way to convert a colour you see on screen to a CMYK or spot colour.

The Pentone books are pretty expensive, so borrowing is a good idea (or visit your printer, if you can).

- [Pantone Coated & Uncoated](https://www.pantone.com/pages/products/product.aspx?pid=1003&ca=1)

[image: Pantone book]

If you can’t do that, then another option is to find something (anything, really) that matches the colour you like, and ask the printer to do their best to match it.

And, if you can’t do that… there are some obvious choices for strong Pantone / CMYK colours, if you want bright red, bright sky blue etc.

This may help:

- [Pantone Color Finder](https://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The 'best' way is to use one's eyes.

Comment: If you are handling print on a regular basis, a Pantone set is essential... not a luxury. Would you borrow tools if employed as a mechanic? No of course not, you will build up your own set. A Pantone set includes several options including a swatch set that is a CMYK to RGB to Pantone comparison. I use it on every new brand to give me a decent chance of a closer match - screen, litho print and spot colour for signage and vinyl graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet, I'll put this in an answer.

I usually use this site: [Encycolorpedia](http://encycolorpedia.com/)

Just paste in the HEX-code and they'll give you more info on the color than you'd ever want or need.

Be aware though that color conversion isn't always straightforward, as has been said before.